# Network configuration for JmDNS on Android. Service added but not resolved

Tags: android, networking, jmdns

I am having trouble resolving mDNS services using JmDNS on Android. The service resolves occassionally but most of the time only serviceAdded() is called and not serviceResolved()! Does anyone know what the issue might be? If there is some network configuration I am missing or such?

I am using ethernet (**eth1**) with the following configuration:

`1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:18:7d:32:77:40 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.191/24 brd 172.18.0.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 2a00:801:19:1:218:7dff:fe32:7740/64 scope global dynamic 
       valid_lft 2591918sec preferred_lft 604718sec
    inet6 fe80::218:7dff:fe32:7740/64 scope link tentative dadfailed 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: sit0: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN 
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
5: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:14:d1:b0:7b:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.3.162/24 scope global eth1
    inet6 fe80::214:d1ff:feb0:7b89/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

`Routing table:
172.18.0.1 dev eth0  scope link 
224.0.0.251 dev eth1  scope link 
192.168.3.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.3.162 
172.18.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.18.0.191  metric 202 
default via 172.18.0.1 dev eth0 
default via 172.18.0.1 dev eth0  metric 202`

Here is the code I am using:

```
            try {
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.3.162");
                jmDNS = JmDNS.create(address);

                serviceListener = new ServiceListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent serviceEvent) {
                        String additions = "";
                        if (serviceEvent.getInfo().getInetAddresses() != null && serviceEvent.getInfo().getInetAddresses().length > 0) {
                            additions = serviceEvent.getInfo().getInetAddresses()[0].getHostAddress();
                        }
                        Log.i("GPSservice.NetworkOperations", "Service resolved: " + serviceEvent.getInfo().getQualifiedName() + " port:" + serviceEvent.getInfo().getPort() + ", " + additions);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent serviceEvent) {
                        Log.i("GPSservice.NetworkOperations", "Service removed: " + serviceEvent.getName());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent serviceEvent) {
                        Log.i("GPSservice.NetworkOperations", "service added");
                        jmDNS.requestServiceInfo(INVENTORY_TYPE, serviceEvent.getName());
                    }
                };
                jmDNS.addServiceListener(INVENTORY_TYPE, serviceListener);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("GPSservice.NetworkOperations", "JmDNS error.", e);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem.

Found the answer here: [JmDNS: Can't resolve service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14340458/jmdns-cant-resolve-service)

Basically just pull down the latest source from the SourceForge SVN repo for 3.4.1 and that will fix the issues with resolving the services

http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/source-repository.html

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work for me. Instead the solution was to switch to mdnsjava which works flawlessly.